# Kullback-Leibler divergence nonnegative proof

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, expected-value, entropy

I am given an example and proof of the [Kullback-Leibler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) divergence:

> Let $\mathbf{p} = (p_1, \dots, p_n)$ and $\mathbf{r} = (r_1, \dots, r_n)$ be probability vectors (so each is nonnegative and sums to $1$). Think of each as a possible PMF for a random variable whose support consists of $n$ distinct values. The *Kullback-Leibler divergence* between $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{r}$ is defined as
>
> $$D(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{r}) = \sum_{j = 1}^n p_j \log_2 (1/r_j) - \sum_{j = 1}^n p_j \log_2 (1/p_j).$$
>
> This is the difference between the average surprise we will experience when the actual probabilities are $\mathbf{p}$ but we are instead working with $\mathbf{r}$ (for example, if $\mathbf{p}$ is unknown and $\mathbf{r}$ is our current guess for $\mathbf{p}$), and our average surprise when we work with $\mathbf{p}$. Show that the Kullback-Leibler divergence is nonnegative.
>
> *Solution*:
>
> Using properties of logs, we have
>
> $$D(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{r}) = - \sum_{j = 1}^n p_j \log_2 \left( \dfrac{r_j}{p_j} \right).$$
>
> Let $Y$ be a random variable that takes on values $r_j/p_j$ with probabilities $p_j$, so that $D(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{r}) = -E(\log_2(Y))$ by LOTUS. Then by Jensen's inequality,
>
> $$D(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{r}) = -E(\log_2(Y)) \ge - \log_2(E(Y)) = -\log_2(1) = 0,$$
>
> with equality if and only if $\mathbf{p} = \mathbf{r}$. This result tells us that we're more surprised on average when we work with the wrong probabilities than when we work with the correct probabilities.

I was wondering how the authors got that $E(Y) = 1$ in $- \log_2(E(Y)) = -\log_2(1)$? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(Y) = \sum p_j \cdot \frac{r_j}{p_j} = \sum r_j = 1 $

Comment: Ahh, yes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Finite_case